# Matplotlib connect scatterplot points with double headed arrow line that can be shown in mplleaflet

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have scatter plot like below:

[image]

I want to connect all blue points with the red point with a double headed arrow line that can be shown using mplleaflet.

Scatter plot shown in mplleaflet:

[image]

Below is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mplleaflet
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def leaflet_plot_stations():

    df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/...') #load lon and lat

    # lon= df['Branch_Lon'].tolist()
    # lat = df['Branch_Lat'].tolist()
    lon = df['Hub_Lon'].tolist()
    lat = df['Hub_lat'].tolist()
    df['demand'] = 20
    df['size'] = df['demand'].apply(lambda x: x / 20 if x > 300 else x)
    print(df)
    size = df['size'].tolist()

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax1.scatter(lon, lat, c='blue', alpha=0.7, s=size, label='Local Hub')
    ax1.scatter(121.222824, 28.901852, c='r', alpha=0.7, s=120, label='Gateway Hub')

    mplleaflet.show()

leaflet_plot_stations()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `annotate` to create arrows, it's slightly easier that creating a `FancyArrowPatch` by hand. Then you just have to iterate through your points are set the right origin/destination

```
points_x, points_y = np.random.random(size=(2,25))
origin_x, origin_y = np.random.random(size=(2,))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(points_x, points_y, 'o', color='blue', alpha=0.5)
ax.plot(origin_x, origin_y, 'o', color='red', alpha=0.5, ms=10)

for x,y in zip(points_x, points_y):
    ax.annotate('', xy=(origin_x, origin_y), xytext=(x,y), arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='<|-|>'))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks. but the lines plotted are not displayed in mplleaflet (map)

Comment: Sorry, I cannot help with mplleaflet, I don't have it installed. Maybe it's a problem of z-order, try passing `zorder=10` inside the call to annotate

Comment: add zorder =10 is still not displaying the arrow lines